# Bitwise operations between 128-bit integers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, sse, logical-operators

I have a question about using 128-bit registers to gain speed in a code. Consider the following C/C++ code: I define two `unsigned long long int`s `a` and `b`, and give them some values.

```
unsigned long long int a = 4368, b = 56480;
```

Then, I want to compute

```
a & b;
```

Here `a` is represented in the computer as a 64-bit number `4369 = 100010001001`, and same for `b = 56481 = 1101110010100001`, and I compute `a & b`, which is still a 64-bit number given by the bit-by-bit logical AND between a and b:

```
a & b = 1000000000001
```

My question is the following: Do computers have a 128-bit register where I could do the operation above, but with 128-bits integers rather than with 64-bit integers, and with the same computer time? To be clearer: I would like to gain a factor two of speed in my code by using 128 bit numbers rather than 64 bit numbers, e. g. I would like to compute 128 ANDs rather than 64 ANDs (one AND for every bit) with the same computer time. If this is possible, do you have a code example? I have heard that the SSE regiters might do this, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, SSE2 has a 128 bit bitwise AND - you can use it via intrinsics in C or C++, e.g.

```
#include "emmintrin.h"          // SSE2 intrinsics

__m128i v0, v1, v2;             // 128 bit variables

v2 = _mm_and_si128(v0, v1);     // bitwise AND
```

or you can use it directly in assembler - the instruction is `PAND`.

You can even do a 256 bit AND on Haswell and later CPUs which have AVX2:

```
#include "immintrin.h"          // AVX2 intrinsics

__m256i v0, v1, v2;             // 256 bit variables

v2 = _mm256_and_si256(v0, v1);  // bitwise AND
```

The corresponding instruction in this case is `VPAND`.

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you for your answer. 
Do you know how to convert two 64-bit numbers unsigned long long int a, b to one __m128i number? I have been looking at the Intel manual but I can't find it. 

As for the SSE2 register, do I have to assume that all modern computers have it? And do I have to add a compilation flag to enable SSE2?

Thanks

Comment: @user2138251 yes all x86 CPUs since the first one that has some SIMD instruction set will include that instruction set for backward compatible. So all Intel CPUs from Pentium 4 will have SSE2. You can even do 512-bit operations with AVX-512 in the future

Comment: @user2138251: you can use the `_mm_set_epi64x` intrinsic to load 2 x 64 bit ints into a 128 bit vector. Any Intel/AMD CPU from the last 10+ years or so has SSE2 minimum. You may need to add `-msse2` to the command line when you compile.